# Display connection information within a ITransformableFilterValues web part

Tags: 2010, filter

I created a filter web part by extending the ITransformableFilterValues interface, similar to this page: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms499375(v=office.12).aspx).  I want to mimic the Microsoft query string filter and display the connection information while a page is being edited.  For example, the query string filter contains the name of the web part being filtered and the parameter(s) being passed.  I looked at all the members in the WebPart class and couldn't find what I was looking for.  Any help would be appreciated.  Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer by looking at the WebPartManager class.  For more information, please visit: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartmanager.aspx)